# Problems with clause "compute" SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cannot find which error is in this syntax, specially clause `COMPUTE`:

```
SELECT 
    D.NOM_DEPT AS DEPARTAMENTO, 
    AVG(E.SALARIO) AS COSTE_RELATIVO
FROM 
    EMPLEADOS AS E 
INNER JOIN 
    DEPARTAMENTOS AS D ON E.COD_DEPT = D.COD_DEPT
GROUP BY 
    D.NOM_DEPT
ORDER BY 
    DEPARTAMENTO
COMPUTE 
    SUM(E.SALARIO) AS COSTE_TOTAL BY DEPARTAMENTO
```

I searched which is the correct syntax for compute by, it seems my code looks right.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypaVQ.png)

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COMPUTE'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjeWr.png)

I would like to know which is the error in this syntax specially "COMPUTE"

Comment: SQL Server - which this presumably is for, based on the error message - doesn't have a `COMPUTE` clause. You'd just add `SUM(E.SALARIO) AS COSTE_TOTAL` to the list of columns being selected - together with the `GROUP BY DEPARTAMENTO` that should achieve the same thing as your `COMPUTE` clause seems to indicate

Comment: The `COMPUTE` clause used to exist but was deprecated - "Rewrite the query to use GROUP BY with ROLLUP"

Comment: Looks like that won't be a "like for like" replacement though as it returned multiple result sets https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/02/sql-server-use-roll-up-clause-instead-of-compute-by/

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server - which I assume this is for, based on the error message, doesn't have a `COMPUTE` clause.

But from reading it, I guess you'll just need to add the `SUM()` to the list of columns being selected - they're already being grouped by `DEPARTAMENTO`.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    D.NOM_DEPT AS DEPARTAMENTO, 
    AVG(E.SALARIO) AS COSTE_RELATIVO,
    SUM(E.SALARIO) AS COSTE_TOTAL 
FROM 
    EMPLEADOS AS E 
INNER JOIN 
    DEPARTAMENTOS AS D ON E.COD_DEPT = D.COD_DEPT
GROUP BY 
    D.NOM_DEPT
ORDER BY 
    DEPARTAMENTO
```